# mysql NOT EXISTS, very slow - How to improve?

Tags: mysql

I've got a small question about trying to ompimise this command I'm running on a table in my database. The table has over 934,836 rows and grows daily by about 12,000.

It holds snapshots of tanks taken daily. What I'm trying to achieve is to see the difference in the snapshots. i.e. see if the player has purchased any new tanks.

The actual snapshot data per account_id is only 100 to 250 rows.

Table wot_snapshots:

```
CREATE TABLE `wot_snapshots` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `snapshot` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=95 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Table wot_tanks_all:

```
CREATE TABLE `wot_tanks_all` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `snapshot` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `account_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `tank_id` int(6) NOT NULL,
  `wn8` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `spotted` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `avg_damage_blocked` decimal(6,2) NOT NULL,
  `capture_points` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `explosion_hits` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `piercings` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `xp` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `survived_battles` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `dropped_capture_points` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `damage_dealt` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `hits_percents` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `draws` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `battles` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `damage_received` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `frags` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `direct_hits_received` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `hits` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `battle_avg_xp` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `wins` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `losses` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `piercings_received` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `no_damage_direct_hits_received` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `shots` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `explosion_hits_received` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `tanking_factor` decimal(2,2) NOT NULL,
  `mark_of_mastery` int(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=934837 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Query:

```
SELECT t1.tank_id, wot_tanks.short_name_i18n FROM wot_tanks_all t1
JOIN wot_tanks ON t1.tank_id = wot_tanks.tank_id
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT tank_id
              FROM wot_tanks_all t2
              WHERE t1.tank_id = t2.tank_id AND account_id = 527080765 AND    snapshot = 60)
AND account_id = 527080765 AND snapshot = 93
```

Output:

```
tank_id short_name_i18n
8465    Panther II
53505   T-127
54865   Light VIC
```

Its currently taking around 30 seconds to run. Am I best to do this all in mysql or offload some of it to PHP?

Any advice and help is greatly appreciated

Thanks,
Jason

Edit: This has just been put together from Google. Still learning!

Comment: Table definitions would help

Answer (score 0):

There is no index on tank id so joining on it will be very slow,I`ve rewritten it to eliminate the self join

```
SELECT t1.tank_id, wot_tanks.short_name_i18n FROM wot_tanks_all t1
JOIN wot_tanks 
ON t1.tank_id = wot_tanks.tank_id
GROUP BY t1.tank_id,wot_tanks.short_name_i18n
HAVING SUM(account_id = 527080765 AND    snapshot = 60)=0
AND SUM(account_id = 527080765 AND snapshot = 93)>0
```

These indexes will speed things up

```
ALTER TABLE wot_tanks_all ADD KEY(account_id ,snapshot )
ALTER TABLE wot_tanks_all ADD KEY(tank_id )
```

Comment: I've not ran the query yet. I'm indexing those fields first. I'm guessing it will take a while to index nearly 1 million rows?